# show transactions for two users in history table within the last 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am trying to get a php table to show only the transactions for the last 24 hours.

The records are stored in a transaction history table and each record has a "buyer_id" and a "seller_id"

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('th.*')
            ->from('TransactionHistory th')
            ->where('th.transaction_end_time > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 86400 * 1))           
            ->orderBy('th.id DESC')
            ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return($query);
```

That query gives me the results I want of all the transactions that happened within the last 24 hours.

The issue is I need to show the transactions within the last 24 hours that the user is involved in either as the buyer or the seller.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('th.*')
            ->from('TransactionHistory th')
            ->where('th.transaction_end_time > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 86400 * 1))
           ->orWhere('th.transaction_buyer_id = ?')
           ->orWhere('th.transaction_seller_id = ?')              
           ->orderBy('th.id DESC')
           ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return($query);
```

This gives me all the results (newer and older than 24 hours)

I need a query (or some other solution) that will show all transactions that you are involved in (either as a buyer or a seller) that are less than 24 hours.

Any ideas, docs, or blindingly obvious solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt S. That was still giving me the same results but in this order it works. Thank you for the assist.

```
      $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('th.*')
        ->from('TransactionHistory th')
        ->where('th.transaction_buyer_id = ? OR th.transaction_seller_id = ?')
        ->andWhere('th.transaction_end_time > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 86400 * 1))
        ->orderBy('th.id DESC')
        ->execute(array($user_id, $user_id), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
  return($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the OR.  You want the time AND the buyer/seller condition. You want OR for just the buyer/seller.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('th.*')
    ->from('TransactionHistory th')
    ->where('th.transaction_end_time > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 86400))
    ->andWhere('th.transaction_buyer_id = ? OR th.transaction_seller_id = ?')
    ->orderBy('th.id DESC')
    ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```